# If $x$, $y$ and $x \oplus y$ are (seperately) independent to $z$, does it imply that $(x,y)$ is independent to $z$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, independence

All the random varibales  are defined in $\mathrm{GF}_2^m$ and $\oplus$ denotes the bitwise exclusive or.

If all the three random variables $x$, $y$ and $x \oplus y$ are (seperately) independent to $z$, does it imply that $(x,y)$ is independent to $z$? Note: $x$ and $y$ do not have to be independent.

We can start by $m=1$ (I believe that the result can easily to be generalized to the case of $m > 1$), that is, all the varibles are sampled from either '1' or '0', and we have $0 \oplus 0 = 0$, $1 \oplus 0 = 1$, $0 \oplus 1 = 1$, $1 \oplus 1 = 0$.

Now I only we that: If  $x$ is independent to $z$ and both of them are uniformed distributed, we have that $x$ is independent to $z \oplus x$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It will be more likely that you will get an answer if you show us that you made an effort.

Comment: I have stuck in this problem for a long time, and now I only have: x is independent to y implies x is independent to x $\oplus$ y

Comment: What do you mean by $\oplus$ here?

Comment: @nobody $\oplus$ is the exlusive or, that is, $0 \oplus 0 =0$,$1 \oplus 0 =1$,$0 \oplus 1 =1$,$1 \oplus 1 =0$

Comment: I have the impression now that there is missing context from your question. If you are only defining $\oplus$ for $0$ and $1$ then is it is clear that $x,y$ and $z$ aren't just any random variables. From your question it appears that they are. You need to add these kinds of details in your question to have a reasonable hope of getting an answer.

Comment: @nobody Thanks a lot, I have updated the question.